# Can't create text in easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver, easeljs

currelty working on a small matching puzzle game. Currently it displays text for the time remaining and the number of tiles that have been macthes. I'm trying to create on for best completion time as well (How fast the person finishes the game) however have been running into a lot of problems. for two variables that I created "txt" and "matchesFoundText" when I type them the autocomplete box will popup and ".text" is displayed as one of the options so i would get something like "txt.text. however I'm not getting that option at all for "bestTimeTxt" and I have no idea as to why this is happening. I did all three variables the same way so I'm at a loss as to why Text is not available to select from for "bestTimeTxt". Here is my entire script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Recipe: Drawing a square</title>
    <script src="easel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


      var canvas;
      var stage;
      var squareSide = 70;
      var squareOutline = 5;
      var max_rgb_color_value = 255;
      var gray = Graphics.getRGB(20, 20, 20);
      var placementArray = []; 
      var tileClicked;
      var timeAllowable;
      var totalMatchesPossible;
      var matchesFound;
      var txt;
      var bestTime;
      var bestTimeTxt;
      var matchesFoundText;
      var squares;

      function init() {
        var rows = 5;
        var columns = 6;
        var squarePadding = 10;

        canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');



        stage = new Stage(canvas);

        var numberOfTiles = rows*columns;

        matchesFound = 0;

        timeAllowable = 5;

        bestTime = 0;

        txt = new Text(timeAllowable, "30px Monospace", "#000");
        txt.textBaseline = "top"; // draw text relative to the top of the em box.
        txt.x = 500;
        txt.y = 0;

        bestTimeTxt = new Text(bestTime, "30px Monospace", "#000");
        bestTimeTxt.textBaseLine = "top";
        bestTimeTxt.x = 500;
        bestTimeTxt.y = 80;



        stage.addChild(txt);
        stage.addChild(bestTimeTxt);

        squares = [];

        totalMatchesPossible = numberOfTiles/2;

        Ticker.init();
        Ticker.addListener(window);
        Ticker.setPaused(false);

        matchesFoundText = new Text("Pairs Found: "+matchesFound+"/"+totalMatchesPossible, "30px Monospace", "#000");
        matchesFoundText.textBaseline = "top"; // draw text relative to the top of the em box.
        matchesFoundText.x = 500;
        matchesFoundText.y = 40;



        stage.addChild(matchesFoundText);

        setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles);

        for(var i=0;i<numberOfTiles;i++){
          var placement = getRandomPlacement(placementArray);
          if (i % 2 === 0){
            var color = randomColor();
          }
          var square = drawSquare(gray);
          square.color = color; 
          square.x = (squareSide+squarePadding) * (placement % columns);
          square.y = (squareSide+squarePadding) * Math.floor(placement / columns);
          squares.push(square);
          stage.addChild(square);
          square.cache(0, 0, squareSide + squarePadding, squareSide + squarePadding);
          square.onPress = handleOnPress;
          stage.update();
        };
      }


      function drawSquare(color) {
        var shape = new Shape();
        var graphics = shape.graphics;

        graphics.setStrokeStyle(squareOutline);
        graphics.beginStroke(gray);
        graphics.beginFill(color);
        graphics.rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);

        return shape;


      }


      function randomColor(){
        var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        var color2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        var color3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
        return Graphics.getRGB(color, color2, color3)
      }


      function setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles){
        for(var i = 0;i< numberOfTiles;i++){
          placementArray.push(i);
        }
      }


      function getRandomPlacement(placementArray){
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*placementArray.length);
        return placementArray.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0];
      }


      function handleOnPress(event){
        var tile = event.target;

        tile.graphics.beginFill(tile.color).rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);

        if(!!tileClicked === false || tileClicked === tile){
          tileClicked = tile;
          tileClicked.updateCache("source-overlay"); 
        }else{
          if(tileClicked.color === tile.color && tileClicked !== tile){
            tileClicked.visible = false;
            tile.visible = false;
            matchesFound++;
            matchesFoundText.text = "Pairs Found: "+matchesFound+"/"+totalMatchesPossible;
            if (matchesFound===totalMatchesPossible){
              gameOver(true);
            }
          }else{
            tileClicked.graphics.beginFill(gray).rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);
          }
          tileClicked.updateCache("source-overlay");
          tile.updateCache("source-overlay");
          tileClicked = tile;
        }
        stage.update(); 
      }


      function tick() {
        secondsLeft = Math.floor((timeAllowable-Ticker.getTime()/1000));

        txt.text = secondsLeft;

       ;

        if (secondsLeft <= 0){
          gameOver(false);
        }
        stage.update();
      }


      function gameOver(win){




        Ticker.setPaused(true);

        for(var i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
          squares[i].graphics.beginFill(squares[i].color).rect(5, 5, 70, 70);
          squares[i].onPress = null;
          if (win === false){
            squares[i].uncache();
          }
        }

        var replayParagraph = document.getElementById("replay");

        replayParagraph.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onClick='history.go(0);'>Play Again?</a>";

        if (win === true){
          matchesFoundText.text = "You win!"
        }else{
          txt.text = secondsLeft + "... Game Over";

        }
      }


      function replay(){
        init();
      }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <header id="header">
    <p id="replay"></p>
  </header>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so apparently the reason why I was having issues is because the x and y positions of the bestTimeTxt variable was causing it to be obscured by the position of everything else.